# wrap an <img> with <div> using javasript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm want to change that

```
<td rowspan="2"><img src="/ORegMx/capito.png" alt="capito"></td>
```

to that

```
<td rowspan="2"><div id="divPage"><img src="/ORegMx/capito.png" alt="capito"></div></td>
```

i tried

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.setAttribute("id", "divPage");
document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > img").appendChild(elem);
```

but it gives

[image]

Also tried

```
var str = '<div id="divPage"><img src="/ORegMx/capito.png"/></div>';
document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2)").replaceWith(str);
```

but it gives

[image]

Appreciate any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to put the `div` *inside* the `img`, but you've said you want the `div` to *wrap* the image. To do that, you need to:

1. Add the div to the `img`'s parent, just before (or after) the `img`, and then
2. Move the `img` into the `div`

For instance:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "divPage";
var img = document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > img");
var parent = img.parentNode;
var next = img.nextSibling;
div.appendChild(img);
parent.insertBefore(div, next);
```

When you append the `img` to the `div`, it's moved (not copied).

*(Also note that you can use the reflected property for `id`, you don't need `setAttribute`.)*

Live Example:

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "divPage";
var img = document.querySelector("#the-img");
var parent = img.parentNode;
var next = img.nextSibling;
div.appendChild(img);
parent.insertBefore(div, next);
```

```css
#divPage {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img id="the-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=The%20Image">
```

Comment: Thank you, last question, is there's shorter code than this ?  or shorter doesn't mean work faster ?

Comment: @user11845248 - Shorter doesn't mean faster. :-) Nothing in the above will be remotely slow. (In fact, I just edited it to make it one line longer, and it will run *ever-so-slightly* faster now. ;-) )

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.

Comment: @user11845248 - Gah! Sorry about that. Fixed above. :-)